# How to put text into SQL select statement

Tags: sql, oracle, select, oracle-apex

I have the following problem.
We are using ORACLE Apex Application Express. We have database with some information inside.
I need to write a SQL select that shows information but I have to follow one rule

> "Price for 'row_name' is 'row_price' usd"

Where the row_name is the name of product and the row_price is sum(price1+price2).

Comment: Can you share the table's structure please?

Comment: There are 3 rows . PRODNAME , DELPRICE , SELLPRICE . The SQL should be "Price for 'PRODNAME' is 'DELPRICE+SELLPRICE'"

Comment: And `row_price` refers to `delprice + sellprice`?

Comment: yes. and all of this have to be in 1 column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `||` operator to concatinate strings:

```
SELECT 'Price for '                  || 
       prod_name                     || 
       ' is '                        || 
       TO_CHAR(delprice + sellprice) || 
       ' usd'
FROM   my_table
```